# AngularJS $scope values not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an application where a user can login. Once logged in the view is divided into 2 - infobar and the main section. The main section gets updated via ng-view. When not logged in infobar is hidden from view using ng-show then shown once logged in. Currently it is hidden as desired when not logged in, but it is not showing when logged in. If you look at the controller, below, I expect that on successful login that `loginStatus.loggedIn` to equal the username, therefore truthy, which should invoke ng-show. Or have I got it wrong?

The code in brief:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="LoginStatus_control" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-show="loginStatus.loggedIn" class="infobar">
        You are logged in as {{username}}
        <button type="button" ng-click="logoutUser()">Logout</button>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
userApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/angular-app/app/', {templateUrl: 'partials/login_part.html'}).
        when('/angular-app/app/overview', {templateUrl: 'partials/overview_part.html', controller: 'Admin_control'}).
        when('/angular-app/app/users', {templateUrl: 'partials/users_part.html', controller: 'Users_control'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/angular-app/app/'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

userApp.factory('OAuth', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location) {
return {
    login: function(rememberCheck, username) {
        if( rememberCheck === true ) {
            localStorage.loggedin = username;
        } else {
            sessionStorage.loggedin = username;
        }
        $location.path('/angular-app/app/overview');
    },

    logout: function() {
        localStorage.loggedin = null;
        sessionStorage.loggedin = null;
        $location.path('/angular-app/app/');
    },

    isLoggedIn: function() {
        if( (sessionStorage.loggedin !== 'null') || (localStorage.loggedin !== 'null') ) {
            if( sessionStorage.loggedin ) {
                return sessionStorage.loggedin;
            }
            else {
                return localStorage.loggedin;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
userApp.controller( 'LoginStatus_control', function( $scope, $rootScope, $route, OAuth ) {
var user = OAuth.isLoggedIn();

$scope.loginStatus = {
    loggedIn: user
}
console.log($scope.loginStatus.loggedIn);
});
```

*EDIT*

[Here's the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LFHLfbOFfEFDijaq5lnc)

Comment: Try using the Batarang chrome plugin to make sure you're actually updating the right $scope. You may find you have more than one you're editing on accident.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Can you post a Plunker or fiddle?

Comment: After you login, doesn't the controller need to somehow call OAuth.isLoggedIn() again to update the value of loginStatus.loggedIn?  In other words, I don't see how the controller is being notified of a successful login, if at first the user wasn't logged in.

Comment: I've now added a Plunker.  @James thanks for letting me know about Batarang, it looks really useful, although when I tested it on this project, it doesn't seem to show anything, just a single `Scope ()` in the model section.  @Mark I did suspect that the issue is with the controller not knowing about the change, but I'm not sure of how to recall that controller at a later point.

Comment: Have you called scope.$apply(); after setting the scope.loginStatus?

Comment: @StuR no I haven't called scope.$apply because I thought that was only to be used when dealing with things from outside of Angular. Is it applicable here, and how would I implement it?